# Corrupt txt file by writing in it from two processes

Tags: python, file, text, parallel-processing, io

Can a txt file get corrupted(not able to read anymore) by opening and writing in it it in the same time by two processes?

this script is run parallely in two processes:

```
while True:
    with open('text.txt', 'w') as FILE:
        FILE.write('test')
```

I already tested it and it doesnt corrupt, **but I would like to be certain**.
I have experience with writing in excel file from python and it can become corrupted pretty easily trying to write in the same time.

Thanks in advance for insight.

Comment: The written data would generally be interspersed between the two write streams in a non-determinstic manner, which may or may not be useful to you, but barring any underlying hardware issues the file can always be read.  However, programs like Excel may have trouble parsing what is being read.

Comment: 2 comments: One, opening the file with `'w'`means the file is deleted and re-written each time. You probably mean `'a'` which appends to the file. Two, I believe the answer is highly dependent on the underlying OS and other factors. In a similar setting (appending to a single log file from many parallel processes) I was surprised to find out that Windows 10 enforces atomicity for writes up to a certain length, meaning that each row (single log entry) was written correctly. But like @metatoaster wrote, the order between rows is non deterministic.

Comment: I rewrite the file with 'w' and I only 'rewrite' one line. No appending.